# How can i download a video from web server and save it on device then play it with default app in android using unity3d?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I want to download a mp4 clip from internet and play it with an external default video player in android devices using unity3d. I designed the requered ui . I wrote code to download it in persistentdata location but Application.openurl does not work anymore on android devices. Please anybody help me with the substitution code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your build settings for you app to a targetSdkVersion of 23 or lower to make it work ! After it's a whole new system and OpenURL() doesn't work the same and it's not the only behavior that is affected.

While I was searching for answers I found this article regarding an important security update on Nougat that could be related to the problem

Comment: unfortunately I can't use lower versions. it looks i should write my own video plyer! thanks anyway.